# How to find out if in Car Mode (Android)?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

is it actually possible to find out via intent (or something else) if the device is currently in Car Mode? I tried to do this with a receiver that has a global variable, however I guess the variable doesn't survive after going through the onReceive ;-)

So is there another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this link after googling for

> Configuration UI_MODE_TYPE_CAR

. Link - http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Samples/techbooster/org/jpn/techbooster/sample/uiModeManager.java.htm

It mentions

`getSystemService(Context.UI_MODE_SERVICE).getCurrentModeType()` will return `Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_CAR` if it is the case.

Comment: This works in all the devices except Nexus devices, any idea? However it is working in Nexus 5 (4.4 version)