# how to detect driving mode in android using java code

Tags: android

Hi i want to develop a app which is able to detect that phone is in driving mode. 
i dont know any idea about it. 
i do lot of googling but all link show driving mode option that available in android phone. (jelly version). 
i dont get any idea for develop it. 
how can i do this in my app. 
is there is any api for driving mode?

i want that feature in my app as like

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.picitup.iOnRoad&hl=en

feature- 24/7 protection with Automatic Driving Detection

Comment: Did you checkout this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508428/how-to-find-out-if-in-car-mode-android/6508646

Comment: sorry, its not what i want. i want that when i am on driving app automatic start working. means user dont have any button to start up.
i want to make my custom driving mode where some extra facilities give 
which i want. so it can be active automatically while on driving. 
i think this app will detect the mobile motion.